# How to set cgroup driver for kubelet in centos7.2?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

Can anybody tell me how to set cgroup driver for kubelet in centos7.2?
the official doc doesn't work... https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#configure-cgroup-driver-used-by-kubelet-on-control-plane-node

details is here: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/17924

Answer (score 1):

use the below command

```
sed -i 's|systemd|cgroupfs|g' /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
```

You can also try below approach to set cgroup driver for docker

```
## Create /etc/docker directory.
mkdir /etc/docker

# Setup daemon.
cat > /etc/docker/daemon.json <<EOF
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "storage-opts": [
    "overlay2.override_kernel_check=true"
  ]
}
EOF

mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d

# Restart Docker
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: thanks, but my /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf file is empty and the official docs said kubelet will autodetect the cgroup driver of docker, but apparently it does not...

Comment: my docker cgroup driver is systemd already，the problem is kubelet seems cannot autodetect docker's cgroup driver and use cgroupfs as it's cgroup driver. write KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd in /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf does not help either.

Comment: yes, you are right. you might need to check and manually update cgroup driver. did you try second approach in my answer